# `gulp build` and dependency vs. devDependency for node

Tags: node.js, npm

Despite all that's been written on `dependency` vs. `devDependency`, I'm still confused how to proceed for modules that are required for a 'build time' step before `npm start` will work.

In my project, one must call `gulp build` before `npm start` will work.  Examples of activities in the build step include transpilation and bundling.  The [official docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json) say specifically not to include transpilers in the dependencies section, but instead in the devDependencies section.  Other best practices suggest that autogenerated code should be kept out of git / modules.  Put these together, though, and I don't understand what to do: someone can't download and run my module without transpiling and building, and those steps can't be completed without the transpiler/bundler/etc. being in the dependencies section.  (Or else "running" is considered "development"?)

How are node projects properly structured for this situation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Anything that is not required to run your app in production mode should be a devDependency.  This will include all of your build tools.

Your `gulp build` should run on your automatic build server, and produce whatever is needed to run your application (transpiled JS or a webpack bundle, for example).  Your build script should be something like:

```
npm install
gulp build 
# or better make it a script in package.json
# npm run build
# remove devDependencies - no longer needed
npm prune --production
npm start
```

Your package.json would contain something like:

```
{
    ... 
    "scripts": {
        "build": "gulp build",
        "start": "NODE_ENV=production node lib/index"
    }
    ...
 }
```

In this contrived example the entry point is lib/index.